# Sencha architect grid is blank. Browser console shows syntax error

Tags: sencha-architect

Im new to sencha, extJS and Architect. So while following the desktop app tutorial after creating a model, a store and binding the grid to the store, the preview shows a blank grid.
I have the records loaded appropriately i think -
[records loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HhpW.png)

But when i preview the application the grid is empty and the browser console has this error-
[blank grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TAOl.png)

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbjsO.png)

[where its showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNl5k.png)

I have not written a single line of code in this tutorial and all of code was self generated. What should i do to populate the grid and not get an error?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to put the store option "autoLoad" to true.